# evaluate bash variables in nested cat

Tags: bash, cat

I have a shell script that looks like

```sh
#/bin/bash

file=File1.sh

cat > ${file} << EOF
file2=subCat
cat > ${file2} << END
echo hello
END

EOF
```

Which produces `File1.sh` with the contents:

```sh
file2=subCat

cat> << END
echo hello
END
```

How can I get `${file2}` to be evaluated as `subCat` in the output file?

Comment: Why would you expect or desire that behavior (implicitly running content of a heredoc as code)? From a security perspective that seems very, _very_ dangerous.

Comment: What is dangerous?

Comment: If the shell behaved the way the question implies it should (running data in heredoc outputs as if that data were code), that would be dangerous. Fortunately, we don't live in that world.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an easier way to reproduce your problem:

```
echo "var=foo"
echo $var
```

It outputs nothing instead of `foo`. This is because outputting a value with an equals sign is not the same as actually assigning a value.

What you asked can be done by assigning the variable first instead of outputting it:

```
#/bin/bash

file=File1.sh
file2=subCat

cat > ${file} << EOF
cat > ${file2} << END
echo hello
END
EOF
```

This will make `File1.sh` contain

```
cat > subCat << END
echo hello
END
```

What you maybe should have asked is how to make the expansion happen in `File1.sh` instead. You can do this by escaping the expansion:

```
#/bin/bash

file=File1.sh

cat > ${file} << EOF
file2=subCat
cat > \${file2} << END
echo hello
END
EOF
```

This will make `File1.sh` contain

```
file2=subCat
cat > ${file2} << END
echo hello
END
```

If you want all expansions to happen in the script, you can also simply quote `'EOF'` instead of each individual one.

Comment: I am interested in the method that assigns the variable before outputting it.  Thank you for helping me understand how to ask the question better.